# .NET Data Layer Thread safety

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am working on my data layer and taking a little different approach, here is one of my many Data Access Objects:

```
class OwnerDaoImpl : IOwnerDao
{
    private const string ID_COLUMN = "Id";
    private const string USERNAME_COLUMN = "Username";
    private const string PASSWORD_COLUMN = "Password";
    private const string NAME_COLUMN = "Name";
    private const string LAST_NAME_COLUMN = "LastName";
    private const string BIRTHDATE_COLUMN = "BirthDate";
    private const string DNI_COLUMN = "DNI";
    private const string EMAIL_COLUMN = "EMail";
    private const string ADDRESS_COLUMN = "Address";
    private const string PHONE_COLUMN = "PhoneNumber";
    private const string PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN = "ProfilePicture";
    private const string DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN = "DistrictId";

    private const string ID_PARAM = "@id";
    private const string USERNAME_PARAM = "@user";
    private const string PASSWORD_PARAM = "@pass";
    private const string NAME_PARAM = "@name";
    private const string LAST_NAME_PARAM = "@lastName";
    private const string BIRTHDATE_PARAM = "@birthDate";
    private const string DNI_PARAM = "@dni";
    private const string EMAIL_PARAM = "@email";
    private const string ADDRESS_PARAM = "@address";
    private const string PHONE_PARAM = "@phoneNum";
    private const string PROFILE_PIC_PARAM = "@profilePic";
    private const string DISTRICT_ID_PARAM = "@disId";
    private const string ROW_COUNT_PARAM = "@rowCount";

    IDatabase db;
    IDbCommand cmd;
    IDataReader dr;

    public OwnerDaoImpl()
    {
        db = DatabaseFactory.GetSqlDatabase();
    }

    public int Insert(Owner toInsert, IDbConnection conn)
    {
        using (cmd = db.GetStoredProcedureCommand(USP_OWNER_INSERT, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(USERNAME_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.Username)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(PASSWORD_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.Password)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(NAME_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.Name)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(LAST_NAME_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.LastName)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(BIRTHDATE_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.BirthDate)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(DNI_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.DNI)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(EMAIL_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.EMail)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(ADDRESS_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.Address)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(PHONE_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.PhoneNumber)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(PROFILE_PIC_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.ProfilePicture)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(DISTRICT_ID_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toInsert.DistrictId)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetOutputParameter(ID_PARAM, SqlDbType.Int));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return (int)((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[ID_PARAM]).Value;
        }
    }

    public bool Update(Owner toUpdate, IDbConnection conn)
    {
        using (cmd = db.GetStoredProcedureCommand(USP_OWNER_UPDATE, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(ID_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.Id)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(USERNAME_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.Username)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(PASSWORD_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.Password)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(NAME_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.Name)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(LAST_NAME_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.LastName)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(BIRTHDATE_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.BirthDate)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(DNI_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.DNI)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(EMAIL_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.EMail)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(ADDRESS_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.Address)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(PHONE_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.PhoneNumber)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(PROFILE_PIC_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.ProfilePicture)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(DISTRICT_ID_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(toUpdate.DistrictId)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetOutputParameter(ROW_COUNT_PARAM, SqlDbType.Int));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return (int)((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[ROW_COUNT_PARAM]).Value > 0;
        }
    }

    public bool Delete(object id, IDbConnection conn)
    {
        using (cmd = db.GetStoredProcedureCommand(USP_OWNER_DELETE, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(ID_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(id)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetOutputParameter(ROW_COUNT_PARAM, SqlDbType.Int));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return (int)((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[ROW_COUNT_PARAM]).Value > 0;
        }
    }

    public Owner Find(object id, IDbConnection conn)
    {
        using (cmd = db.GetStoredProcedureCommand(USP_OWNER_FIND, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(ID_PARAM, DaoUtil.ValueOrDbNull(id)));
            using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int ID_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(ID_COLUMN);
                int USERNAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(USERNAME_COLUMN);
                int PASSWORD_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PASSWORD_COLUMN);
                int NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(NAME_COLUMN);
                int LAST_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(LAST_NAME_COLUMN);
                int BIRTHDATE_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(BIRTHDATE_COLUMN);
                int DNI_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(DNI_COLUMN);
                int EMAIL_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(EMAIL_COLUMN);
                int ADDRESS_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(ADDRESS_COLUMN);
                int PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PHONE_COLUMN);
                int PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN);
                int DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN);

                Owner owner = null;
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    owner = new Owner
                    {
                        Id = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<int>(ID_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Username = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(USERNAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Password = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PASSWORD_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Name = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        LastName = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(LAST_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        BirthDate = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<DateTime>(BIRTHDATE_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        DNI = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(DNI_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        EMail = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(EMAIL_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Address = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(ADDRESS_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        PhoneNumber = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        ProfilePicture = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        DistrictId = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<int>(DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN_INDEX, dr)
                    };
                }
                return owner;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Owner> FindAll(IDbConnection conn)
    {
        using (cmd = db.GetStoredProcedureCommand(USP_OWNER_FINDALL, conn))
        using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int ID_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(ID_COLUMN);
            int USERNAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(USERNAME_COLUMN);
            int PASSWORD_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PASSWORD_COLUMN);
            int NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(NAME_COLUMN);
            int LAST_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(LAST_NAME_COLUMN);
            int BIRTHDATE_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(BIRTHDATE_COLUMN);
            int DNI_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(DNI_COLUMN);
            int EMAIL_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(EMAIL_COLUMN);
            int ADDRESS_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(ADDRESS_COLUMN);
            int PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PHONE_COLUMN);
            int PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN);
            int DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN);

            List<Owner> lOwner = new List<Owner>();
            Owner owner = null;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                owner = new Owner
                {
                    Id = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<int>(ID_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    Username = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(USERNAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    Password = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PASSWORD_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    Name = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    LastName = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(LAST_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    BirthDate = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<DateTime>(BIRTHDATE_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    DNI = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(DNI_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    EMail = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(EMAIL_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    Address = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(ADDRESS_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    PhoneNumber = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    ProfilePicture = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                    DistrictId = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<int>(DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN_INDEX, dr)
                };
                lOwner.Add(owner);
            }
            return lOwner;
        }
    }

    public Owner Login(Owner owner, IDbConnection conn)
    {
        using (cmd = db.GetCommand(USP_OWNER_LOGIN, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(USERNAME_PARAM, owner.Username));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(db.GetParameter(PASSWORD_PARAM, owner.Password));

            using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int ID_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(ID_COLUMN);
                int USERNAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(USERNAME_COLUMN);
                int PASSWORD_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PASSWORD_COLUMN);
                int NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(NAME_COLUMN);
                int LAST_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(LAST_NAME_COLUMN);
                int BIRTHDATE_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(BIRTHDATE_COLUMN);
                int DNI_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(DNI_COLUMN);
                int EMAIL_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(EMAIL_COLUMN);
                int ADDRESS_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(ADDRESS_COLUMN);
                int PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PHONE_COLUMN);
                int PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN);
                int DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = dr.GetOrdinal(DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN);

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    owner = new Owner
                    {
                        Id = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<int>(ID_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Username = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(USERNAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Password = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PASSWORD_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Name = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        LastName = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(LAST_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        BirthDate = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<DateTime>(BIRTHDATE_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        DNI = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(DNI_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        EMail = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(EMAIL_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        Address = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(ADDRESS_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        PhoneNumber = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        ProfilePicture = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<string>(PROFILE_PIC_COLUMN_INDEX, dr),
                        DistrictId = DaoUtil.ValueOrDefault<int>(DISTRICT_ID_COLUMN_INDEX, dr)
                    };
                }
                return owner;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using a single IDbCommand as instance member and also a single IDataReader, my question is, if a user calls, for example, FindAll() and another calls Insert, will there be a conflict since both of them are using the same instance of IDbCommand?, can another thread change the IDbCommand or are there different instance of it? please feel free to point out any other flaws in my code since I'm trying to get the best outcome possible, thanks for your assistance

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What do you gain from it. You will have issues. Declare them in the scope you are using them and dispose when done. Amongst other things, the data reader will throw an exception about being related to another open command if things happen in the (in)correct order.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 could you please give me and example of when and how this could happen? Right now my code is running completely synchronously so I have no need to use other threads, if I use this data object for a web application, will several users use the same instance?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not thread safe, due to the shared state of `cmd` and `dr`.

For example: If a thread calls `Insert` and disposes `cmd` just as another thread is about to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, you will run into problems.

I don't see any reason for that shared state though, those variables should be local to the methods using them. `db` should be fine though, since you only ever change it in the constructor.

---

As a side note, I would seriously consider using a ORM like Entity Framework and stop writing hundreds of lines of data access code.